# Python NLTK: supervised learning for classifying unlabelled data, no labelled data available

Tags: python, nltk, classification

I'm trying to extract time based information from text, for which as far as I know labelled data doesn't exist. The goal is to take sentences and extract information on when, for example, a task is due. That could be in many forms - some of which are ambiguous (a number between 1 and 12 is a common representation for a time, but of course not always). It seems that the best way to proceed would be to train a classifier to detect such data.

However, while NLTK makes thousands of sentences available, it doesn't have labelled data for this particular purpose. I'm wondering if there's a sensible method I can use to classify some data manually, in such a way that I can later use that as train/test data for a classifier. Ideally it would be graphical and allow clicking on the relevant terms, but I expect that's an absurd request. Alternatively, is there a better method I could use, considering I probably don't want to manually classify thousands of sentences? Am I on the right lines at all here, or is a classifier system simply not viable without labelled data available?

Thanks,
Callum

Comment: There is software for this http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/time.shtml

Comment: Hmm, that looks quite useful. [Found a similar Python project if anybody's interested too](https://github.com/cnorthwood/ternip). If it's okay I'd like to keep this open and see if anybody else has any comments.